# c++ automatic deduction of derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, derived-class

So say I have a base class like this:

```
class BaseNode
{
    BaseNode* nodeA;
    BaseNode* nodeB;
};
```

And derived classes along the lines of:

```
class DecisionNode : public BaseNode
{
    //lots of variables and functions about decision making
};

class ActionNode : public BaseNode
{
    //lots of variables and functions about performing actions
};
```

And a sort of logic class:

```
class Logic
{
    std::vector<BaseNode*> nodes;//contains DecisionNodes and ActionNodes...

    void handleNodeAutomatically(BaseNode* node)
    {
        //some funky deduction code....
        //send the node to the relevant function below
    }

    void handleDecisionNode(DecisionNode* node)
    {
        //perform decision-specific code here....
    }

    void handleActionNode(ActionNode* node)
    {
        //perform action-specific code here....
    }
};
```

What would be your suggestions as to how I should implement the 'handleNodeAutomatically' function?  Or is my whole idea of how this should work completely rubbish(do tell me if it is!)

I know I can do stuff like:

```
if(dynamic_cast<ActionNode*>someNode != NULL) //it turns out it's an action
```

but that seems a bit convoluted to me.  And I believe dynamic_cast has a bit of overhead associated with it too.

I could also just have one big actionAndDecisionNode class with *all* the attributes of both classes and a boolean "isDecisionNode" value, and just test for that, or a  'nodeType' enum, but again these methods just feel a bit messy.

So, if it pleases you, take a shot at filling in the blanks in the 'handleNodeAutomatically' function.  Or, alternatively, tell me this plan is utterly doomed to fail, and tell me a better way of doing it.

Thanks!

Comment: What you are trying to do looks like a CRTP pattern aka static polymorphism.

Comment: Sounds like a useful new concept...(a googlin' I shall go....)

Comment: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)
It will not make your code less messy, though.

Comment: Yes, found the wikipedia page...not too worried about my code looking messy really!

Comment: @Argh: Your question indicates that you are (rightfully so) worried about your code looking messy. Otherwise you'd have gone with your `dynamic_cast` solution.

Comment: The answer below is generally a better choice than dynamic_cast, but both are workable easy to understand solutions.  You seem to be worried about things being slow, but unless all your program does is call empty functions all day neither solution is likely to even show up on a profile.

Comment: I guess...I'm kind of more worried about the system being nice and intuitive to use.

Comment: Check out the so-called visitor pattern, too. It avoids cluttering a class hierarchy with lots of empty, virtual functions if something is only needed in a derived class but required in the baseclass interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could perhaps have a method in all three classes and call it from the `Logic` class:

```
class BaseNode {
    // ...
    virtual void foo();
};

class ActionNode : public BaseNode {
    // ...
    void foo(); // implements the Action version of foo()
};

class DecisionNode : public BaseNode {
    // ...
    void foo(); // implements the Decision version of foo()
};
```

and then:

```
class Logic {
    void handleNodeAutomatically(BaseNode* node)
    {
        node->foo();
    }
};
```

---

**Note:**
Refer to comments below (by @BasileStarynkevitch and @ChristianHackl) for some technical details.

Comment: I believe `foo` should often be `virtual` inside `BaseNode`

Comment: Yes...looks quite nice when you put it like that...for some reason I can't remember, I don't think I want to do that though...

Comment: @Argh Why not? It's a clean and logically pleasant way of implementing what you have. That's the power of polymorphism.

Comment: @Argh: Why not? It seems to be the correct way (minus a few technical details missing, e.g. the necessity of a virtual destructor).

Comment: @jadhachem: You should add a virtual destructor to this example, and consider adding `virtual` (pre-C++11) or `override` (C++11) to the overridden functions to document the fact that they override a virtual function.

Comment: Oh alright, maybe I'm mistaken...I'll go with the consensus until / if I remember why...